# Unaligned Plotly Graphs (Bars + Pies) When Running Shiny RMarkdown Document

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-markdown, slidy

I created a slidy report in markdown that using runtime shiny, in of the slides there are several plotly bar and pie charts. However, all the latter are going unligned (legend is half showing or sometimes overlapping with itself), see a snapshot:

[[image]

That's the only slide I'm facing this problem with, I tried setting the margin and y/x axis dimensions but nothing worked.

Any help please, my code below (plotly graphs parts):

```
shinyApp(

ui <- fluidPage(shinythemes::themeSelector(), useShinyjs(), useShinydashboard(),
              
                
                dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Plotly Graphs"),
dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(style = "position : fixed",
                selectInput(inputId = "year_1",
                                     label = h4("Select The Year"),
                                     choices = unique(data$Year),
                            width = '71.7%'),
                            
                         
                         pickerInput(inputId = "list_1",
                                     label = h4("Select Entity"),
                                     choices = c ("Department1", "Department2","Department3", 
 "Department4", "Department5", "Department6", "Department7","Department8", "Department9",  "Department10",  "Department11",
                                     selected = data$Department, 
                                     multiple = TRUE,
                                     options  = list(
                                       `actions-box` = TRUE,
                                       size = 10,
                                       width = '74.2%',
                                       `selected-text-format` = "count > 3",
                                       icon = icon("sync")
                                     )),
                
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Rating1",
                                   label = h4("Filter1"),
                                   choices = c("one", "two", "three", "four"),
                                   selected = data$Rating1),
               
                         checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Rating2",
                                            label = h4("Filter2"),
                                            choices = c("one", "two", "three", "four"),
                                            selected = data$Rating2,
                                            inline = TRUE,
                                            width = "75%")
                                       
                                     ))
                         
                         
                         
))
  ,
 
dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    tabBox(side = "right", title = h4("Rating1 vs. Rating2 - Overall", align ='center'), id = "Rating2",
         tabPanel( h6("Rating1"),
                  plotlyOutput(outputId = "plotly_3"), verbatimTextOutput("Rating21Selected"), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE),
        
        tabPanel(h6("Rating2"),
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "plotly_2"), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = TRUE)),
        
    
  tabBox(side = "right", title = h4("Rating1 vs. Rating2 - Departments",  align ='center'), id = "Rating2 ",
         tabPanel(h6("Rating1"),
                 plotlyOutput(outputId = "plotly_7"), verbatimTextOutput("Rating2Selected"), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = TRUE),
        
        tabPanel(h6("Rating1 "),
        plotlyOutput(outputId = "plotly_6"), status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE, autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE, scrollY = TRUE))
  )))),

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## Reactive Filter1
  Rating1_Filter <- reactive({
    data %>%
      filter(Year %in% input$year_1) %>%
      filter(Department %in% input$list_1) %>%
      filter(Rating1 %in% input$Rating1)
    
  })
  
  ## Reactive Filter2
   Rating2_Filter <- reactive({
    data %>%
      filter(Year %in% input$year_1) %>%
      filter(Department %in% input$list_1) %>%
      filter(Rating2 %in% input$Rating2)
    
  })

  
   ## Rating1 - Overall 
    
  Pie_1 <- plot_ly(labels = ~Rating1, values = factor(1),
                   legendgroup = ~Rating1,
                   textinfo = 'label+value',
                   textposition = 'inside',
                   hoverinfo = 'text',
                   hoverlabel = list(font=list(size= '16')),
                   marker = list(colors = "red"),
                   showlegend = T)
                   
  output$plotly_2 <- renderPlotly({
    Pie_1 %>% 
      add_pie(data = Rating1_Filter()) %>%
      layout(title = "Rating1", 
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
  })
  
  ## Rating1 - Across Department
  
  output$plotly_6 <- renderPlotly({
    Rating1_Filter() %>% 
      count(Department, Rating1) %>% 
      plot_ly(x = ~Department, y = ~n, color = ~Rating1, colors = c('one' = 'red', "two" = "yellow","three" = "green")) %>% 
      layout(title = "Rating1",  hoverlabel = list(font=list(size= '16')),
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, showlegend = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, showlegend = FALSE, title = FALSE))
    
  })
  
  ## Rating2 - Overall
  
   ### Coding the colors:
  colors_list <- list(
    "one" = "red",
    "two" = "yellow",
    "three" = "green"
  )
  
  data$color <- dplyr::recode(data$Rating2, !!!colors_list)
  
  ## Rating2 - Overall (Pie Chart):
  Pie_2 <- plot_ly(labels = ~Rating2, values = factor(1),
                   legendgroup = ~Rating2,
                   textinfo = 'label+value',
                   textposition = 'inside',
                   hoverinfo = 'text',
                   marker = list(colors = ~color),
                   hoverlabel = list(font=list(size= '16')),
                   showlegend = T)
  
  
  output$plotly_3 <- renderPlotly({
    Pie_2 %>% 
      add_pie(data = Rating2_Filter()) %>%
      layout(title = "Rating2", 
             xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
  })
  
  ## Rating2 - Across Department
  
  output$plotly_7 <- renderPlotly({
    Rating2_Filter() %>% 
      count(Department, Rating2) %>% 
      plot_ly(x = ~Department, y = ~n, color = ~Rating2, colors = c('one' = 'red', 'two' = 'yellow', 'three' = 'darkgreen')) %>% 
      layout(title = "Rating2", barmode = 'stack',  hoverlabel = list(font=list(size= '16')),
             legend = list(bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'),
             xaxis = list(tickangle = 40),
             yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, showlegend = FALSE, title = FALSE))
    
  })
,

  options = list(height = 1000)
)
```

Any support please, that's the only slide out of alignment when I run the document. I changed my data for privacy.
Thanks

Update: When I run the same shiny app separately it worked well but when I incorporated it into my slide presentation, the legends are out of alignment for all the plotly graphs, I do not know why this is happening, I will try to find another package to do my graph and incorporate them into my slidy, maybe it will work then.

Comment: This code does not work. Additionally, if you need to protect the data, then make some. (Use a built-in set and rename columns, for example.) It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample code you've attempted, any errors/warnings received, what type of output or outcome you’re expecting, and sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: @Kat Thanks for your comments, thr code works but it misses some inputs as I removed things for data privacy. However, I figured out that the real problem is using plotly with slidy presentation, the only way you get it work is by leaving the charts empty with now data and once the user inputs some data from the side Panel then everything including the legends will go in tge right shape but if you let all filters selected by default then the graphs will be unaligned. Thanks for your tip I will try my best next time I post a question.